# What is the meaning of the value Solana Pay / Decaf writes to the Memo?

Tags: solana-pay, memo, solana-spaces

I purchased a T Shirt using Solana Pay recently and the [transaction has written something unusual to the `memo` program](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2Wgzyv1fFFiF4jd8ckPvSJa2eRBHF7pj3wbeTpEzMvqzpfx1jpUgWUZbJW9h915rxWccNqZ9ksFjP7PVVckArZtX):

```
{
  "parsed": "qqS5qxxEjMg7mSup0rBI",
  "program": "spl-memo",
  "programId": "MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr"
},
```

The [spec for Solana Pay](https://docs.solanapay.com/spec#memo) says:

> The value must be a URL-encoded UTF-8 string that must be included in an SPL Memo instruction in the payment transaction.
> The wallet must URL-decode the value and should display the decoded value to the user.

However `qqS5qxxEjMg7mSup0rBI` is already URL decoded and the meaning still not obvious. Normally [`parsed` would be human readable](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2L8kkNX3aAza4nYY6YRU8QdCest6UirPy6i6aPd4B5fSFcUh4PUjc2SvADnPocddJdjVxLhYCWcj3MscZYDutQL1).

**What is the meaning of the value Solana Pay writes to the Memo?**

This seems to be some kind of code (maybe a receipt?) for Solana Pay.

**Update**: it looks like the merchant using Solana Pay in this case is Decaf so this is a Decaf question. Oddly [Decaf's receipt is `XgVU1qK4i4zXKanjHZpr`](https://www.decaf.so/receipt/XgVU1qK4i4zXKanjHZpr) which doesn't quite match the transaction note of `qqS5qxxEjMg7mSup0rBI`.

Comment: The Value here can be anything and it's an optional parameter in the solana pay url schema so it is something that the creator of the project has added and can be meaningful to them.

Answer (score 1):

Solana Pay, the protocol, does not use this field for anything in particular. It is an optional field that allows the user of the protocol to attach a memo to the payment that can be used later.

I recommend reaching out to the merchant that you purchased the t-shirt from :)

Comment: Thanks TJ! I'll chase it with Solana Spaces (the vendor in question) then.

Comment: PS - for things like this, where it's a helpful comment pointing to somewhere to find an answer rather than an answer, it's best to use comments. Thanks TJ! 

Comment: Update: Solana Spaces uses Decaf, so it's a Decaf question.